# how to pass value in v-select in vue

Tags: vue.js, v-select

i m new to vue (version 2.5) in my project i had install v-select i go through document and got confuse on few thing 
here is my code

```
  <template>
   <div class="wrapper">


             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="name">Category</label>
                   <v-select  label="category_desc" options="category"></v-select>
                 </div>
               </div>
          </div>
  <button type="button" variant="primary" class="px-4" @click.prevent="next()">next</button>
       </div>
 </template>     

 <script>
   export default {
     name: 'Addproduct',
    data () {
             return {

                 category:[]


             }
           },
     mounted() {
             this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/categories') .then(function (response) {
                 console.log(response.data);
                this.category=response.data

                 })
                 .catch(function (error) {
                   console.log("error.response");
                 });
         },
```

method:{
       next(){
       // console.log('value of v-selection not option' ) eg id 1 has 'country' so i want id 1 in method next() i.e in console.log
        }
       }
     
now my problem is that how i can pass this axios responded success value to v-select option and second this how i can get selected value of v-select for eg;- when user click on next button how i can get which value is selected in v-select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind options to category.  i.e. `v-bind:options` or short hand `:options` I would also suggest you use a method to make your ajax call, and then call the method in `mounted()` instead.  Also you probably want a `v-model` on that select so I added that in the  example.

First in your template...

```
 <v-select  v-model="selectedCategory" label="category_desc" :options="category"></v-select>
```

Then in your script definition...

```
data(){
   return{
     category:[],
     selectedCategory: null,
   }
},
methods:{
    getCategories(){
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/categories')
           .then(function (response) {
               this.category=response.data
             }.bind(this))
           .catch(function (error) {
               console.log("error.response");
            });
  }
},
 mounted(){
   this.getCategories(); 
 }
```

Here is a working jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/mghbLyva/3/

Comment: your code working fine but if i add ajax response then it stop working  this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/categories') .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
              // this.category=response.data
               this.category=[response.data];
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log("error.response");
                }); i.e not output

Comment: thanks that working i just add var _this=this outside ajax and then inside ajax   _this.category=[response.data]

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. I suggest you use `.bind(this)` to get `this` into scope as it is cleaner.  See my edit above.   If my answer helped please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about [this select component](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Api/Props.html)? The simplest usage is to put a v-model attribute on your v-select. Then this variable will automatically reflect the user selected value.

If you need to specify options, which you might, then you also need to provide a value prop and listen for @change.

Comment: v-model  select  add  in v-select it throw error select not define can you show me some example in new so i got confuse